# Application starts letter boxing after loading icon assets in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios9

Does anyone know why my app letterboxes on iPhone 6 and 6plus in simulator after uploading icon assets? Before uploading them there was no letter boxing and after removing them it stopped letterboxing.

Xcode 7+. Built for iOS 9.3.

Comment: Are you using a launch screen file or launch images?

Comment: I used the 'asset catalog creator' app to take my logo and turn it into the dims required then dumped it into my project.  Then the letter boxing started.  Would that have changed any settings?